# Why it can run in my device but it didn't display the map?I am beginner of SDK please explain clearly

Tags: java, android, eclipse, google-maps

This is my MainActivity
it is wrong about level of API ??
i am using Google API
API level 18

```
package com.example.map;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;

import com.google.android.maps.GeoPoint;
import com.google.android.maps.MapController;
import com.google.android.maps.MapView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        MapView myMap = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapView);

        final MapController controller = myMap.getController();
        LocationManager manager = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        LocationListener listener = new LocationListener(){

            @Override
            public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
                controller.setCenter(new GeoPoint((int)location.getLatitude(),(int)location.getLongitude()));

            }

            @Override
            public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status,
                    Bundle extras) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

        };
        manager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, listener);

    }


}
```

This is my Manifest
The uses_permission is necessary ??

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.map"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >


    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="11"
        android:targetSdkVersion="11" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>

    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <uses-library
        android:name="com.google.android.maps" />

        <meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
    android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
        <meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
    android:value="API_KEY"/>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.map.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

This is my activity_main
My layout is it correct??

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:id="@+id/mapView"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"/>
```

Comment: Check internet connectivity. Make sure you have turned on Google map v2 for android in api console

Answer (score 0):

If you're seeing a grayed tile background where a map should be, you are likely using the `wrong api key`.  You need a production key for a device that is different from the debug key for the map api.

Comment: @AA user also working with Map Controller is it working?

Comment: i run it , got display icon , package name  and white blank screen, after few second it become black and stop it.
wrong API key?? Can explain clearly??
Thank You.

Comment: @user3366285 What map api level are you using v2 or v3?